# RNSScreen not found in the UIManager

Tags: react-native

`Im making a react native app and when I added navigation between pages this error occurred. Please help me because I'm going crazy.

> Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSScreen" was not found in the UIManager.

> This error is located at:
> in RNSScreen (created by AnimatedComponent)
> in AnimatedComponent
> in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by InnerScreen)
> in Suspender (created by Freeze)
> in Suspense (created by Freeze)
> in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
> in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
> in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
> in Screen (created by MaybeScreen)
> in MaybeScreen (created by CardStack)
> in RNSScreenContainer (created by ScreenContainer)
> in ScreenContainer (created by MaybeScreenContainer)
> in MaybeScreenContainer (created by CardStack)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by Background)
> in Background (created by CardStack)
> in CardStack (created by HeaderShownContext)
> in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
> in SafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
> in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by StackView)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by GestureHandlerRootView)
> in GestureHandlerRootView (created by StackView)
> in StackView (created by StackNavigator)
> in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
> in NavigationContent
> in Unknown (created by StackNavigator)
> in StackNavigator (created by SignedInStack)
> in EnsureSingleNavigator
> in BaseNavigationContainer
> in ThemeProvider
> in NavigationContainerInner (created by SignedInStack)
> in SignedInStack (created by App)
> in App
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by AppContainer)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by AppContainer)
> in AppContainer
> in FitLoupe(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
> ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleSetJSResponder' of null, js engine: hermes
> ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleClearJSResponder' of null, js engine: hermes
> ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleSetJSResponder' of null, js engine: hermes
> ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleClearJSResponder' of null, js engine: hermes
> ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleSetJSResponder' of null, js engine: hermes
> ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleClearJSResponder' of null, js engine: hermes
> ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleSetJSResponder' of null, js engine: hermes
> ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleClearJSResponder' of null, js engine: hermes
> ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleSetJSResponder' of null, js engine: hermes
> ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleClearJSResponder' of null, js engine: hermes
> ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleSetJSResponder' of null, js engine: hermes
> ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleClearJSResponder' of null, js engine: hermes
> ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleSetJSResponder' of null, js engine: hermes
> ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleClearJSResponder' of null, js engine: hermes
> ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleSetJSResponder' of null, js engine: hermes
> ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleClearJSResponder' of null, js engine: hermes
> ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleSetJSResponder' of null, js engine: hermes
> ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleClearJSResponder' of null, js engine: hermes

Any help on how to resolve this? I installed everything I need.

Comment: Would you please post your `package.json`? Most of the reason for this is missing `react-native-screens`.

Comment: I resolved the problem somehow but I have another issue and it's regarding different emulator. For example when I run iPhone SE 3rd gen my app works just fine, but when I start it on iPhone 14 pro same error occurs... Any tips? And by the way I checked my package.json file and it has react-native-screens

Comment: Maybe some cache issue? Try again by closing all the Metro Server and simulator, rebuild the project. Also, sometime delete the app in simulator and reinstall may help. If those solution makes no different, please edit your question with `package.json` and `react-native` code.